# Why function return empty object?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, move-semantics

This is c++11. Straightforward sort function for stack using two stacks. 
While debuging tempStack inside sort() function is filling correctly but sort() function is returning empty object?

I was trying to add std::move() or std::forward() but this is incorrect. General sort() algorithm is correct! This code compiled successfully. Some mistakes with c++11 (move semantics)!

My ideas (not working correctly!):
return forward>(tempStack);
return move(tempStack);

Code (sort()):

```
template<typename T>
Stack<T> sort(Stack<T> &input)
{
    if(input.isEmpty()) return Stack<T>();
    Stack<T> tempStack;
    while(!input.isEmpty())
    {
        T element = input.pop();
        while(!tempStack.isEmpty() && tempStack.peek() > element) input.push(tempStack.pop());
        tempStack.push(move(element));
    }
    return tempStack;
}
```

Code (Stack class):

```
template <typename T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack() : top(nullptr), stackSize(0)
    {}
    Stack(Stack &&other) : top(std::move(other.top)), stackSize(std::move(other.stackSize)) {}
    ~Stack() { while (!isEmpty()) pop(); }
    void push(T &&value)
    {
        auto n = new Node(std::forward<T>(value), top);
        top = n;
        ++stackSize;
    }
    T &peek()
    {
        if (!top) throw StackIsEmptyException();
        return top->value;
    }
    T pop()
    {
        if (!top) throw StackIsEmptyException();
        auto value(std::move(top->value));
        auto n = top;
        top = n->next;
        delete n;
        --stackSize;
        return value;
    }
    bool isEmpty() const { return !top; }
    size_t size() const { return stackSize; }
    class StackIsEmptyException
    {};
private:
    struct Node
    {
        Node(T &&v, Node *n): value(std::move(v)), next(n)
        {}
        Node(const T &v, Node *n): value(v), next(n)
        {}
        T value;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node *top;
    size_t stackSize;
};
```

Code (main()):

```
Stack<int> s;
s.push(34);;
s.push(3);
s.push(31);
s.push(98);
s.push(92);
s.push(23);

cout << sort(s).peek() << endl;
```

Comment: Check your copy constructor, it doesn't actually make a copy.

Comment: Why return move(tempStack);//call move constructor

Comment: There's no copy constuctor?

Comment: Unless your move constructor does some kind of zeroing of the original object, there's no way it will know to not clean up or anything.

Comment: Oops I did mean your move constructor, yes.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but in the `sort` function, that initial `if` statement isn’t needed. The function will do exactly the same thing without it.

Answer (score 3):

What happens when this line runs?

```
return tempStack;
```

1. `tempStack` is moved to a temporary object.
2. `tempStack` is destroyed.
3. Temporary object is returned.

In step 1, the `top` and `stackSize` of `tempStack` are copied to the temporary object (that's what your move constructor does).
In step 2, all the items in the stack are deallocated.
In step 3, this returned object's `top` is now pointing to deallocated memory.

Your move constructor should set the moved-from object's `top` to NULL (and presumably also `stackSize` to 0) so that that object won't deallocate anything when it's destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to inform the moved object that it should not destroy its resources. For instance you may use a guard preventing cleaning stack if the object was moved.

Like:

```
Stack(Stack &&other) : top(std::move(other.top)), stackSize(std::move(other.stackSize)) { other.moved = true; }

~Stack() { if (!moved) while (!isEmpty()) pop(); }
```